# PHP MySQL 3 tables Foreign Key Join data from 1 Table into the other 2

Tags: php, mysql, join, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables `Order`, `CheckoutStatus`, and `Statuses`. There is a foreign key in `Order` and `CheckoutStatus` that references the `Statuses` table.

I need to join `CheckoutStatus` to `Order` linked by the `PO` column and I need to join `Statuses` to `Order` and to `CheckoutStatus`.

**Here is the data in the tables**

Order table

```
`PO` = 123456
foreign key `Statuses_id` = 2
```

CheckoutStatus

```
`PO` = 123456
foreign key `Statuses_id` = 0
```

Statuses

```
`id` 0 = Complete
`id` 2 = Completed
```

How do I write my SQL statement so that I can have a result like this.

```
Order
123456
Completed
CheckoutStatus
123456
Complete
```

This SQL statement I'm using does not display anything unless I remove one of the `JOIN Statuses` section of the statement.

```
SELECT * FROM `Order` JOIN `Statuses` ON Statuses.id = Order.Statuses_id JOIN `CheckoutStatus` ON Order.PO = CheckoutStatus.PO JOIN `Statuses` ON Statuses.id = CheckoutStatus.Statuses_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two JOINs on table Statuses. You need to use table aliases to distinguish the two relationships :

```
SELECT 
    `Order`.PO,
    s1.Status,
    s2.Status
FROM 
    `Order` 
    JOIN `Statuses` s1 ON s1.id = Order.Statuses_id 
    JOIN `CheckoutStatus` ON Order.PO = CheckoutStatus.PO 
    JOIN `Statuses` s2 ON s2.id = CheckoutStatus.Statuses_id
```

Comment: besides using PHP to remove the `Statuses_id` from displaying in the output, is there something in the SQL statement I can add? Just want to display the PO number and the Status value of Complete and Completed as seen above in the question.

Comment: @Mike : query updated. You might have t change the name of the column that hold the status value (I assumed « Statuses.value »).

Comment: What is the reason to change the column name? The column names in the `Statuses` table are `id` and `Status`.

Comment: @Mike... this information was not part of your original post so I had to assume. It is easy to change the query once you have the logic explained

Comment: Ok now I know what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this can get a little bit confusing you can split the query and on the basis of its fetched result, you can fetch further more

```
      $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM `Order` JOIN `Statuses` ON Statuses.id = 
               Order.Statuses_id JOIN `CheckoutStatus` ON somthing"
                $result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result4) > 0)
             {
             while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4))
             {
             $sql5='SELECT * FROM //the result of before joining other two '
                    }
                 }
```

something like this